# How to optimize a black box function in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a function to optimize, which I can't get the derivative or Hessian or Jacobian out of (hence the "black box" in the title). Say my function looks like this:

```
def my_fun(some_int, some_other_int, some_string):
    return float(some_int + some_other_int + len(some_string))
```

note that I only perform the cast to show that the function returns a floating point number.

The search space / constraints / bounds (or however you call it) would be:

```
some_int = [1..10] # int interval
some_other_int = [1, 2, 3] # int discrete
some_string = ["methodA", "methodB", "methodC"] #discrete
```

How should I formulate the problem in python? This is what I've searched so far:

- Scipy [optimizers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) don't seem to accept constraints for the Nelder-Mead Simplex (or the Powell method) that is applicable in my case
- [PyOpt](http://www.pyopt.org/examples/examples.groups.html) ... well I can't get around using multivariate objective function
- There's also [Pyswarm](http://pythonhosted.org/pyswarm/). Does anyone know how to do this in Pyswarm?

Any thoughts?

Comment: About a constrained Nelder-Mead: I had the same problem once and took the matlab-code from http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd--fminsearchcon and rewrote it into python specifically for my problem. Hope that helps.

Comment: Be more precise about the ```black-box``` nature. If function-evaluation is cheap, there should be no problem using finite-differences to obtain gradients.

Comment: Yes I'd say it's fairly cheap. The evaluation itself takes about 6 seconds but there's a fairly small search space . Could you please provide an example in that case?

Comment: Scipy will do this automatically if no gradient-information given. But despite the fact that 6 secs may be costly for this, you got a much bigger problem: the discrete state-space. the only optimizers within scipy supporting this are probably basinhopping and differential_evolution (which i never used). They are both gradient-free and possible approaches here. But let me warn you: non-convex mixed discrete-continuously black-box (noisy) optimization is the worst of all scenarios. An alternative (but try the scipy ones first): [rbfopt (part of Coin OR)](https://github.com/coin-or/rbfopt)

Comment: You could give https://scikit-optimize.github.io/ a try. It implements sequential model based optimisation for objectives that are expensive to calculate and for which you do not know the gradient. (I am one of the authors of skopt)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an hyperparameter optimization package such as https://github.com/Dreem-Organization/benderopt/

It supports the different type of your parameters.